# How to use javascript module on an HTML page in a second inline script

Tags: javascript, html, module

I have a JavaScript module `mymmodule.js` exporting a list:

```
export var mylist = ['Hallo', 'duda'];
```

Normally this module is used in other modules and this works fine. But additionally I want to use the export(s) of the module as-is in an inline script on an HTML page. I tried to copy the exports to the `window` object:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module">import * as mm from './mymodule.js';  window.mm = mm;</script>
</head>

<h1>MyMain</h1>
<p>
    <div id = "info">...</div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('info').textContent = window.mm.mylist;
</script>            
</html>
```

but I get the error "window.mm is undefined" in the console. I tried referencing `mm.mylist` instead of `window.mm.mylist` with no better result.

How can I reference the exports of a module in a second inline script on the HTML page?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that modules are execute at the same stage as pscripts with the `defer` attribute](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#defer), i.e. *after* reading the page and executing JavaScript in script tags.

Therefore, when the browser sees

```
document.getElementById('info').textContent = mm.mylist
```

the `mymodule.js` script hasn't been executed and the `mm` object is not available yet.

To mitigate this you need to run code referencing exports from `mymodule` after the DOM is completely loaded, e.g. in the `onload` event:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="module">import * as mm from './mymodule.js';  window.mm = mm;</script>
</head>

<h1>MyMain</h1>
<p>
    <div id = "info">...</div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('info').textContent =    mm.mylist;
    }
</script>            
</html>
```